# Filter column by records matching a timezone in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I want to check whether any rows in my column (`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`) are *not* stored using UTC. Is there a query I can write to match values that are stored with a TZ offset of 1 or 8 or 11 or (not 0)?

Answer (score 3):

No, there is not. The type name [`timestamp with time zone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html) can be misleading. The time zone is **not stored at all**, it just serves as input / output modifier and all values are stored as UTC internally.

More:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860)
- [Time zone storage in PostgreSQL timestamps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28876266/939860)